# Getting direct URL while clicking javascript button on specific website

Tags: javascript, html, url, firefox

I am displaying an online internal website.

Upon clicking on a button "A" it processes a task, and goes to another HTML page. However, this direct address is like "hidden" (hard to explain).

For example, for each page I am accessing by simple button click, it's always the same URL (like http://host.com for *every* page I display from them).

I am using Firefox, and I need to know how to get the exact HTML address (or direct URL) used for displaying these full new pages. I managed to do it few months ago, but not anymore.

It will help me to automate some tasks and bashing programs. I am openned to any linux browser in case you find a way to help me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: It's possible that it IS always the same URL. It could be that the page is being built by POST data from a form, for example. If this is the case, you won't be able to recreate that page from just a URL unless you somehow send the post data along with it, using something like curl for example.

Comment: Yes, actually, it seems to be the case. Even when I try to see the html code now, I don't see it all, but only the one of the main page. It's really weird.

Answer (score 0):

it sounds like domain masking is used. you could check the source and see if a frame is being used on the page. the source should indicate the src of the frame, revealing the location of the page.

```
<frame src="page.html">
```

Comment: Yes, you seems to be right. However, while checking the html code, the problem is that it considers the page before the javascript action

Answer (score 0):

If the button uses `window.open` to navigate to the url, you could override that method and intercept the url there:

```
var oldOpen = window.open;

window.open = function(){
    console.log(arguments[0]);
    oldOpen.apply(window, arguments);
};
```

Comment: it's actually using search_sub()

Comment: Is that some function that you defined?  How does it set the URL internally?